# How do I print values of a function for multiple inputs in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

[Pyhton Code Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us9Yx.png)

Completely new to programming so excuse my ignorance. Pretty clear what I was trying to do in the image attached I think. Had to give up and just rewrite the function. Why isn't it accepting g(x)?

```
def g(x):
    return (x**7+3*x)/4
```

and then

```
for x in range(4,14):
    print g(x)
```

didn't work so I used

```
for x in range(4,14):
    y=(x**7+3*x)/4
    print(y)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post all code verbatim as text.

Comment: You sorta answered your own question. What's different about the `print` line in your first attempt than your second?

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks a lot! @ChristianDean

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, print is a function, so requires parentheses.

Use `print(g(x))` instead of `print g(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's working. The only change I did to your code is to rename the variable in the for loop and add the extra parens that was already mentioned.

```
def g(x):
    return (x**7+3*x)/4
g(5)
Out[28]: 19535.0
for num in range(4,14):
    print(g(num))

4099.0
19535.0
69988.5
205891.0
524294.0
1195749.0
2500007.5
4871801.0
8957961.0
15687139.0
```

Comment: Yeah that did the trick, thanks!