# Generate a random character not found in another string

Tags: python, string, random

I have a string which has some chars and I need to generate a random uppercase char which is not found in my string.

Example:
str = "SABXT"
The random char can be any char which is not in str

I tried:

```
string.letters = "SABXT"
random.choice(string.letters)
```

but this do the opposite, it generates the char from my str

Comment: Why are you assigning to the module object, `string`? `string.letters = "SABXT"`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a list of characters that are not in your string, and then use `random.choice` to return one of them.

```
import string
import random

p = list(set(string.ascii_uppercase) - set('SAXBT'))
c = random.choice(p)
```

Granted, the subsequent `random.choice` may seem redundant since the `set` shuffles the order, but you can't really depend on the set order for randomness.

Comment: Dang it, I've gotten slower over the school year :P +1

Comment: Nah, had to respond to [this guys comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46575590/how-do-i-print-values-of-a-function-for-multiple-inputs-in-python?noredirect=1#comment80104700_46575590) (rather, just see what he said).

Answer (score 1):

```
import string,random
prohibitted = "SABXT" 

print random.choice(list(set(string.ascii_uppercase)-set(prohibitted)))
```

Is one way.

Another might be:

```
import string,random
prohibitted = "SABXT" 
my_choice = random.randint(0,26)
while char(ord('A')+my_choice) in prohibitted:
    my_choice = random.randint(0,26)
print char(ord('A')+my_choice)
```

Yet another way might be:

```
import string,random
my_choice = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
while my_choice in prohibitted:
    my_choice = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
```

Comment: Any `random.choice` call on a set generates: `TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing` (python3.4)